# Merge ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, compiler

The new [ES6 module syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) is very nice, but not yet supported by browsers. I'd like to use the new syntax while I'm developing, then compile the modules into one JS file which can run in browsers. I haven't found any program that can do this.

I know that [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#transform-plugins-modules) or similar ES6-transpilers can convert `import/export` to `require()`, and eg. Browserify allows to use it in browsers, but I don't want to load multiple JS files at runtime. One compiler could convert all ES6 modules into one JS file, just like how we create one binary executable from multiple .c / .h files.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing some bits here.

- [Babel.js](https://babeljs.io/) is a compiler to translate your JS code written using future features not yet supported by JS engines into ES5+ code (depending on the `preset` you configure here).
- [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) it's a bundler that takes a bunch of JS files/modules and **bundle** them into one (or more) JS file(s).

If you want to write your own software/app in ES6+ Javascript and bundle it into a single ES5+ Javascript file you need to setup a compiler (like [Babel.js](https://babeljs.io/) ) and a bundler (like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en) ).
The build chain is usually the following:

`Your code --> Babel compiler --> Bundler --> Your code in ES5+`

If you google `Babel Browserify boilerplate` or `Babel Webpack boilerplate` you're likely to find pre-cooked projects.